# Async function never returns while waiting for a nested Promise to fulfill

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

In the below code there is an `outer` function and an `inner` function. `outer` is supposed to `await` `inner` and return when it completes. `inner` returns a `Promise` which is fulfilled after a timeout. I expect the `outer` function to return right after this `Promise` is fulfilled:

```
const outer = async () => {
    let counter = 0;
    const inner = async () => {
        console.log('inner');
        return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
            if (++counter === 3) {
                console.log('fulfill');
                fulfill();
                return;
            }
            setTimeout(() => inner(), 1000);
        });
    };
    return await inner();
};
outer().then(() => console.log('outer done'));
```

`outer` never completes though. Note that there is no `outer done` output:

```
inner
inner
inner
fulfill
```

In the following code `outer` completes. It returns a `Promise` itself, and the `inner` function fulfills it:

```
const outer = async () => {
    return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
        let counter = 0;
        const inner = async () => {
            console.log('inner');
            if (++counter === 3) {
                console.log('fulfill');
                fulfill();
                return;
            }
            setTimeout(() => inner(), 1000);
        };
        inner().catch(err => reject(err));
    });
};
outer().then(() => console.log('outer done'));
```

Output:

```
inner
inner
inner
fulfill
outer done
```

I thought that the behavior should be similar in both these cases. Can anybody see and explain the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never called the `fullfill` function in `inner`. You created a bunch of new Promises and you only told the last promise that it has been resolved.

Let us take a look at your async task:

```
{
    if (++counter === 3) {
        console.log('fulfill');
        fulfill();
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(() => inner(), 1000);
}
```

In the first call to `inner`, ie this part:

```
return await inner();
```

`counter` is at 0. That means the entire `if` block is not executed. In the rest of the code, it never called the `fulfill` function and thus the promise never got resolved.

If this code (or this style of code) exists in your production code base, my advice would be you should rewrite it.

To fix it *really quickly* you can probably do this:

```
setTimeout(() => inner().then(() => fulfill()), 1000);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ekutfroq/)

Comment: How do you explain the presence of `fulfill` log in such case? It proves that the code reaches that point.

Comment: @YuryFedorov You fulfilled the last promise, but don't forget you have created *four* new promises. The log actually proves that it *did* not reach it, since there should be 4 lines instead of 1.